# TFS REST API: How to "Make requests on behalf of others"?

Tags: rest, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I want my VSTS extension (installed on-prem TFS2015.3) to be able to do specific requests on behalf of a admin/service account ("Make requests on behalf of others")

Background: I manipulate (WorkItem) Process Template, specifically the GLOBALWORKFLOW (only on team-project level) in my extensions typescript, but the user of the extension in Web Access is NOT a project-admin so he is not allowed to use the function updateWorkItemTypeDefinition() - Non-Project-Admins get "Access denied" even if I gave that custom group every permission available ("Edit project-level-information" permissions for project-level GLOBALWORKFLOWs? Still didn't work for custom groups, only for Project Admin Accounts).

It seems I'm forced to impersonate a project admin /service account which is allowed to change the global workflow in the project

How do I impersonate in extension typescript code on-prem TFS and REST (1. not .NET and 2. without changing to basic auth, saw that solution already somewhere else - but I'm very sure I cannot request that change in my organization)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Edit: PAT is not a solution since I'm working on-prem (2015.3)

Comment: There are some things in the Process Template level that can only be edited when a user has some collection level permissions. Fields and Link Types for example are stored at the collection level, not at the Project level, so you need permissions on a higher plane than the project.

Comment: @jessehouwing doesnt hurt, if I can get my TFS extension finally to impersonate a service account, even collection-level service account is OK then

Answer (score 1):

You can impersonate user through vsts-node-api.

There are many function to impersonate user, such as Basic, NTLM, PWA (VSTS) etc..., you can check these function [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/blob/master/api/WebApi.ts).

```
import * as vm from 'vso-node-api';

// your collection url
var collectionUrl = "XXX";


let authHandler = vm.getNtlmHandler("[user name]","[password]","[workstation optional]","[domain optional]"); 

var connect = new vm.WebApi(collectionUrl, authHandler);
```

[There](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api) is the sample that you could refer to.

Comment: AFAIK there is no Personal Access Token with on-prem TFS2015. It's in VSO and on-prem starting with TFS15RC1

Comment: @FerdiÖztürk I updated my answer, there are many functions to impersonate user, for on-premises TFS, you can use getNtlmHandler function.

Comment: THXs for the update, I want to try it but have trouble with importing the vso-node-api in my .TS. Steps: 1. npm i vso-node-api 2. referenced per /// <reference path='../node_modules/vso-node-api/WebApi.d.ts' /> 3. import vsonode = require("vso-node-api"); - didn't work. Can you please tell me how to import vso-node-api module correctly or what am I missing? (not using typings install because the .d.ts are in the vso-node-apis node_module folder already)

Comment: @FerdiÖztürk Using this code: import * as vm from '../node_modules/vso-node-api/webapi';

Comment: THXs that worked fine, gret help! remark: for UpdateWorkItemTypeDefinition() with vso-node-api I cannot use interfaces from ("TFS/WorkItemTracking/Contracts") anymore, switched to import WorkItemTrackingInterfaces = require("./node_modules/vso-node-api/interfaces/WorkItemTrac‌​kingInterfaces"); Still I get errors because it cannot resolve "NodeJS.ReadableStream" from WorkItemTrackingApi.d.ts in vso-node-api - what am I missing here? Output:
Error TS2503 Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'. 
Error Build:Cannot find namespace 'NodeJS'.

Comment: my node version is v6.7.0

Comment: @FerdiÖztürk Can you share the code you currently use?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT shared my code as answer. But I think vso-node-api is missing a node.d.ts

Comment: also "http" cannot be found in vso-node-api: Build:Cannot find module 'http'. ValueListChanger xxx\HttpClient.d.ts 1 
Error TS2307 Cannot find module 'http'.

Comment: @FerdiÖztürk Run following commands and then try again: typings install dt~node --global --save         typings install dt~q --global --save

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT already tried that before because I had the idea the typedefs were missing, but made it worse. showed a very very long list of TS2435 and TS2307 errors for code in typings\globals\node\index.d.ts - Could it be I'm not running the recommended combination of node, tsc and perhaps targeting ES6 is experimental still in tsc? I also tried with Typescript 1.7 and 2.0. Also long list of errors... Can you please share which versions are you using and what are you targeting for getting it to work? Did you reproduce it?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT Perhaps it's easier to have a quick Lync session, would you please ping me with your MSFT lync/skype4business here: ferdi.oeztuerk.ext@siemens.com